# node.js http.request event flow - where did my END event go?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, coffeescript, node.js-connect

I am working on a cunning plan that involves using node.js as a proxy server in front of another service.

In short:

1. Dispatch incoming request to a static file (if it exists)
2. Otherwise, dispatch the request to another service

I have the basics working, but now attempting to get the whole thing working with Sencha [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) so I can access all the kick-ass middleware provided.

All of the action happens in *dispatchProxy* below

```
connect(
  connect.logger(), 
  connect.static(__dirname + '/public'),
  (request, response) ->  
    dispatchProxy(request, response)
).listen(8000)

dispatchProxy = (request, response) ->  

  options = {host: host, port: port, method: request.method, headers: request.headers, path: request.url}

  proxyRequest = http.request(options, (proxyResponse) ->
    proxyResponse.on('data', (chunk) ->
     response.write(chunk, 'binary')
    )

    proxyResponse.on('end', (chunk) ->        
     response.end()
    )

    response.writeHead proxyResponse.statusCode, proxyResponse.headers    
  )

  request.on('data', (chunk) ->
    proxyRequest.write(chunk, 'binary')
  )

  # this is never triggered for GETs
  request.on('end', ->
    proxyRequest.end()
  )

  # so I have to have this here
  proxyRequest.end()
```

You will notice ***proxyRequest.end()*** on the final line above.

What I have found is that when handling GET requests, the END event of the request is never triggered and therefore a call to proxyRequest.end() is required. POST requests trigger both DATA and END events as expected.

So several questions:

- Is this call to proxyRequest.end() safe? That is, will the proxyResponse still be completed even if this is called outside of the event loops?
- Is it normal for GET to not trigger END events, or is the END being captured somewhere in the connect stack?

Comment: The `finish` event seems to work as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255507)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is less the `end` event and more the `data` event. If a client makes a GET requests, there's headers and no data. This is different from POST, where the requester is sending data, so the `on("data")` handler gets hit. So (forgive me for the JS example, I'm not that familiar with coffeescript):

```
var http = require('http');

// You won't see the output of request.on("data")
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  request.on("end", function(){
    console.log("here");
  });
  request.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log("I am here");
    console.log(data.toString("utf8"));
  });
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

If I make a curl call to this server, the data event never gets hit, because the `GET` request is nothing more than headers. Because of this, your logic becomes:

```
// okay setup the request...
// However, the callback doesn't get hit until you
// start writing some data or ending the proxyRequest!
proxyRequest = http.request(options, (proxyResponse) ->
  // So this doesn't get hit yet...
  proxyResponse.on('data', (chunk) ->
   response.write(chunk, 'binary')
  )

  // and this doesn't get hit yet
  proxyResponse.on('end', (chunk) ->
   // which is why your response.on("end") event isn't getting hit yet        
   response.end()
  )

  response.writeHead proxyResponse.statusCode, proxyResponse.headers    
)

// This doesn't get hit!
request.on('data', (chunk) ->
  proxyRequest.write(chunk, 'binary')
)

// So this isn't going to happen until your proxyRequest
// callback handler gets hit, which hasn't happened because
// unlike POST there's no data in your GET request
request.on('end', ->
  proxyRequest.end()
)

// now the proxy request call is finally made, which
// triggers the callback function in your http request setup
proxyRequest.end()
```

So yes you're going to have to manually call `proxyRequest.end()` for `GET` requests due to the logic branching I just mentioned.

Comment: Using your example script above, the request.on("end") callback *is* triggered on GET, but the data event is not ... which makes me think something funky is happening inside the connect infrastructure ...

Answer (score 1):

my experience is that `request.on('end',)` is not *consistently* called unless it's a POST. I suspect the event (of someone making a http.request) is over before the script gets a chance to detect it.

Comment: I'm wrestling with this very same issue.  it's maddening.